# Facades: aliasloader not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to write my own classes in Laravel that I can use in my controllers. I'm trying this with facades.

This is my folder structure:

```
app
    classes
    facades
    serviceproviders
```

I autoloaded them in composer.json

```
    "app/facades",
    "app/classes",
    "app/serviceproviders"
```

My class (app/classes/DateRange.php)

```
<?php namespace myMethods;

class DateRange {
    public function doSomething()
    {
        echo 'Doing something!';
    }
}
```

My facade (app/facades/DateRangeFacade.php)

```
<?php namespace myMethods\Facades;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class DateRangeFacade extends Facade {
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'DateRange'; }
}
```

My Serviceprovider (app/serviceproviders/DateRangeServiceProvider.php)

```
<?php namespace myMethods;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DateRangeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['DateRange'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new DateRange;
        });

        $this->app->booting(function()
        {
            $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('DateRange', 'myMethods\Facades\DateRangeFacade');
        });
    }
}
```

Also added 'myMethods\DateRangeServiceProvider' to providers array in app.php

Opening the site, it displays 'Class 'myMethods\AliasLoader' not found'. Found a solution on stackoverflow to put a '\' before AliasLoader:: but that doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use or namespace all the things:

```
<?php namespace myMethods;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader;

class DateRangeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['DateRange'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new DateRange;
        });

        $this->app->booting(function()
        {
            $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('DateRange', 'myMethods\Facades\DateRangeFacade');
        });
    }
}
```

This is required (and you cannot simply use \AliasLoader) because AliasLoader is not an Alias in Laravel, it's a class, so you need to tell PHP exactly where it is.